# Installing android studio on a mac mini using USB

Tags: android, macos, installation

I need to install Android Studio in a third world country with very poor internet connection. Is it possible to download everything I need into a USB stick in the US and then go there and install?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible but you would need to download both Android Studio and the SDK. You can do so from this page http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html.

Downloading Android Studio is simple enough. Copy it to USB and then transfer it to your machine and install. You will need an internet connection to update Android Studio when updates come out though.

The SDK is a bit different. Download the SDK tools from the above link. Once that is download save the SDK tools to a USB. The SDK can be saved anywhere and transferred to another machine easily as Android Studio points to an external location for the SDK. In this case, once the SDK is downloaded, update the SDK and get the API's and emulator images that you want by calling either of the two below:

- On Windows, double-click the SDK Manager.exe file at the root of the
  Android SDK directory.
- On Mac or Linux, open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory
  in the Android SDK, then execute android sdk.

Then you can transfer the SDK tools folder (which should now have grown in size) wherever you want on your machine and just point Android Studio to it by following the below steps:

1. File -> project Structure into Project Structure
2. SDK Location (in the left hand panel)
3. Select Android SDK location (for versions of Android Studio before 1.0.1, press +, add another sdk)